# How to send a file to the server using XMLHttpRequest and formdata

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, .net-4.5, multipartform-data, filereader

I've checked out a few articals and I cannot seem to successfully send a file to the server using XMLHttpRequest and the FormData object.

When I debug my c# .net code in the pageload of the upload.aspx file the files property of the request object always has a count of 0.

What part am I missing so that I can send files to the server asynchronously?

**--HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="upload" accept="image/*" onchange="handleFile(this.files)" name="file" />
```

**--js**

```
function handleFile(files) {

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var file = files[0];
    var imageElem = document.createElement("img");
    debugger
    fileReader.onload = (function (img) { return function (e) { img.src = e.target.result; }; })(imageElem);

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

    document.getElementById("images").appendChild(imageElem);

    uploadFile(file);
}

function uploadFile(file) {
    debugger
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/upload.aspx", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

**--C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = null;
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        file = Request.Files[0];
        //file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/myfile.txt"));
    }
}
```

**--SnapShot**

[image: The File Being Posted]

[image: The Request.Files Object Count]

---

**--------------------Found The Answer Here-----------------------------------**

[File API File Upload - Read XMLHttpRequest in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181789/file-api-file-upload-read-xmlhttprequest-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to remove this line of your code:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Hope it helps!