# ASP.NET MVC HttpPostedFileBase pass file to server without input file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is a posibility not to use input file tag and pass file to server. For example, i want to pass image that is shown in `<img />` tag.

Comment: Pass it as base 64 encoded string format of bytes and convert it back to bytes in server side

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `XHR` object to upload a file to the server. This approach does not use `HttpPostedFileBase`. There's a good example of how to do it here: [File API File Upload - Read XMLHttpRequest in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181789/file-api-file-upload-read-xmlhttprequest-in-asp-net-mvc)