# How can I handle HTTP error responses when using an iframe file upload?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http, iframe

I am using the following dirty workaround code to simulate an ajax file upload. This works fine, but when I set `maxAllowedContentLength` in `web.config`, my iframe loads 'normally' but with an error message as content:

```
dataAccess.submitAjaxPostFileRequest = function (completeFunction) {
    $("#userProfileForm").get(0).setAttribute("action", $.acme.resource.links.editProfilePictureUrl); 
    var hasUploaded = false;
    function uploadImageComplete() {
        if (hasUploaded === true) {
            return;
        }
        var responseObject = JSON.parse($("#upload_iframe").contents().find("pre")[0].innerText);
        completeFunction(responseObject);
        hasUploaded = true;
    }
    $("#upload_iframe").load(function() {
        uploadImageComplete();
    });
    $("#userProfileForm")[0].submit();
};
```

In my Chrome console, I can see

> POST http:/acmeHost:57810/Profile/UploadProfilePicture/ 404 (Not
>   Found)

I would much prefer to detect this error response in my code over the risky business of parsing the iframe content and guessing there was an error. For 'closer-to-home`errors, I have code that sends a json response, but for`maxAllowedContentLength`, IIS sends a 404.13 long before my code is ever hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can do if you have no control over the error. If the submission target is in the same domain than the submitter and you are not limited by the SOP, you can try to access the content of the iframe and figure out if it is showing a success message or an error message. However, this is a very bad strategy.

Why an IFRAME? It is a pain.

If you want to upload files without the page flicking or transitioning, you can use the JS File API : [File API File Upload - Read XMLHttpRequest in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181789/file-api-file-upload-read-xmlhttprequest-in-asp-net-mvc)

The support is very good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

For old browsers that does not support the File API just provide a normal form POST. Not pretty... but ok for old browsers.

**UPDATE**

Since there is no chance for you to use that API... Years ago I was in the same situation and the outcome was not straightforward. Basically, I created a upload ticket system where to upload a file you had to:

- create a ticket from `POST /newupload/` , that would return a GUID.
- create an iframe to `/newupload/dialog/<guid>` that would show the file submission form pointing to `POST /newupload/<guid>/file`
- serve the upload status at `GET /newupload/guid/status`
- check from the submitter (the iframe outer container) the status of the upload every 500ms.
- when upload is started, hide the iframe or show something fancy like an endless progress bar.
- when the upload operation is completed of faulted, remove iframe and let the user know how it went.

When I moved to the FileReader API... was a good day.

Comment: I am coding for IE9! [gnashing teeth] and the whole project infrastructure is ajax and knockout based with otherwise strict MVVM modelling. To break just one upload into a vanilla post will be a headache.

Comment: My current concern here is how can my browser detect a 404.13 error  in the iframe, but I can't communicate it to me, except via the console. Surely there is some js I can use to access the browser's knowledge of this event?

Comment: I doubt it, but please if you find a way post it here :)

Comment: I have just resorted to a generic error if my iframe content isn't the expected json :-(