# Send of XMLHttpRequest not Binding with Controller Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following JavaScript to setup a progress bar for an upload process

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadButton").click(function (event) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#fileSelector").get(0).files;
        //data.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }
        http.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        http.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        http.open("POST", "./Tools/Upload");
        http.send(data);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
function progressHandler(event) {
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    $('.bar').width(percent);
}
function completeHandler() {
    $('.bar').width(100);
}
```

The controller method is

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpContext context) { ... }
```

Now, when I click on my button the JavaScript fires and I can see the file name in my `data` `FormData` object. However, I get a

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

When I change the method signature to

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) { ... }
```

The method gets called but the `files` parameter is null.

**What parameter type should I be using with my `http.send(data);` call?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your `Upload` parameter is named `files` but your posting `files[i].name`. Not tested but it probably should be just `data.append('files', files[i]);`

Comment: Oh good god... Silly, I think this is the issue. Thanks, will report back.

Comment: Note also you can pass the file name as the 3rd parameter `data.append('files', files[i], files[i].name);` as per [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Wait, I don't think this is it. I am currently appending a correct KeyValuePair to the `FormData` object. How will using "files" help here, the parameter name in the controller is irrelevant...

Comment: Should be no different than a standard submit with `<input type="file" name="files" >` which will bind to your controller, but if you changed it to `<input type="file" name="MyFile.text" >` it wont. (but it will still be in `Request.Files`)

Comment: This has not helped. Thanks very much for your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code with the correct request header.

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

Comment: This has not helped. The problem persists... Thanks for your time.

Comment: This makes sure that the files are sent correctly to the server.

Comment: @Killercam please read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181789/file-api-file-upload-read-xmlhttprequest-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: That does not help me I am afraid.